# Spotify Developer Application logo

Tags: spotify

I am looking to set my application logo for Spotify. I cannot see anywhere to upload a logo for my application. How can I upload my logo for a Spotify application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is for the Web API and the "My apps" part, then it is not currently possible to upload a logo for your application. It is in our backlog to be able to do so, I cannot provide a date for when it will happen though.

Comment: Any update on this? I was hoping to upload a logo too if possible